# Working with access connection string

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have an encrypted access data Base and I want to add its connection string to app.config but I don't know its syntax.

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add  name="ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=jaame.accdb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have worked with simple access but about encrypted one I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example of Access 2007 connection:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\jaame.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

There isnt any special arguments for connection string for encrypted Access databases.

Encrypted Access database cannot be opened with an editor but can be accesed.

It is not your question, but if you want some more protection you should use other mechanisms or other databases.